# C# Populate dictionary directly from SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, sql-server, dictionary, sqldatareader

In a program that I've been working on, there are three steps to get the data into a Dictionary that's been created:

1. execute the SQL command
2. pull those results into a `DataTable`, then
3. pull the `DataTable` into the `Dictionary`

Code:

```
var myDr = myLookup.ExecuteReader();
dt.Load(myDr);
customerLookup = dt.AsEnumerable()
    .ToDictionary(key => key.Field<string>("code"),
    value => value.Field<string>("customerText"));
```

My question is, is it possible to “cut out the middleman,” so to speak, and pull the data from the `SqlDataReater` directly into the Dictionaries? Or is it necessary to pull it into a `DataTable` first? If what I'm looking to do is possible, can someone please post code for me to try?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Try this :             myDr.Read();
            while(myDr != null)
            {
                customerLookup.Add(myDr["code"], myDr["customerText"]);myDr.Read();
            }

Answer (score 8):

You can just loop through the rows returned by the reader:

```
var customerLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
using (var reader = myLookup.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        customerLookup[(string)reader["code"]] = (string)reader["customerText"];
    }
}
```

You should be aware that if there are any duplicate codes, subsequent code values will overwrite previous ones in the dictionary. You can use `customerLookup.Add()` instead if you'd rather an exception be thrown in such a case.

Answer (score 2):

Not only can you, but you definitely should. The code, as you show it, shows a complete lack of knowledge of how .NET works.

Some of the code I am suggesting may be considered "overkill" for the question at hand, but it does demonstrate some best practices.

```
Dictionary<string, string> customerLookup = new Dictionary<string, string>();
using (var reader = myLookup.ExecuteReader())
{
    int ordinalCode = reader.GetOrdinal("code");
    int ordinalCustomerText = reader.GetOrdinal("customerText");
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //this code assumes the values returned by the reader cannot be null
        customerLookup.Add(reader.GetString(ordinalCode), reader.GetString(ordinalCustomerText))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You should use [SqlDataReader.Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.read(v=vs.110).aspx) method.